# Android pause/resume a service

Tags: android, service, resume

I want to pause the media scanner service and then do some work and resume the service. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Bit more explanation, is the service yours? Why do you need to pause it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the `MediaScanner`, then, no, you cannot pause a scan operation. However, you can have it scan one file at a time, so you can pause/do work/resume yourself.